# MTP authorization

Tags: usb, mtp

I accidentally selected "Deny" when I connected my Galaxy S5 to my computer and the little notification came up when asking permission to access my photos. Now my computer is not recognizing my phone. I need help to transfer my pics from phone to computer.

Answer (score 0):

Pull down the notification bar and tape on *charging on USB, Tape for other USB options* then choose *Transferring media files*. It should be detected now.

[image]
[image]